# List of VHDL external name in package

Tags: package, external, vhdl, modelsim

I'm trying to write an VHDL package to create a list of external names to use them in my test bench. I'm not sure if it is possible to declare an external name in an package but the compiler doesn't throw an error.

However if i try to simulate my test bench with ModelSim 10.0b i get an error by loading the design:

> Cannot reference the signal ... before it has been elaborated.

Although the compile order is correct, i guess there is a problem within the loading order during simulation startup. All packages are loaded before the design is loaded. Is there a chance to force ModelSim to load the external name package later?

Code by @user3099274 inserted from comment for readability:

```
package external_name_package is
  alias signal1 is << signal .tb_top_cfg.TB_TOP_E_INST.DUT.signal1 : std_logic >>;
  alias signal2 is << signal .tb_top_cfg.TB_TOP_E_INST.DUT.signal2 : std_logic >>;
end package external_name_package;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of external names"?  Is this a new `type` that you are creating?  Are you creating an actual `signal`?

Comment: Can you show a *small* example of what you have so far?  I don't think we understand what you are trying to ask...

Comment: Hello, here an example for the package. I want to use the aliases in different entitys by using this package package external_name_package is  alias signal1 is << signal .tb_top_cfg.TB_TOP_E_INST.DUT.signal1 : std_logic >>; alias signal2 is << signal .tb_top_cfg.TB_TOP_E_INST.DUT.signal2 : std_logic >>;  end package external_name_package;

Answer (score 4):

VHDL design processing is done in multiple steps, first with analysis and later
elaboration.  The analysis checks syntax and semantics for all the separate
design units.  Elaboration creates the entire design by combining the different
design units into one large design based on the hierarchy.

It is in the elaboration process that the external names, with hierarchy
references, are checked and connected to the referenced signals etc.  VHDL's
elaboration rules specify that the design is elaborated in depth-first
top-to-bottom order.  When an external name is meet during the elaboration
step, it must be possible to determine the location, which requires that the
location of the external name reference has already been elaborated.

If you try to make a package with signals, then the external names in the
package are elaborated in the start of the test bench module, thus before the
DUT is elaborated, and it is therefore not possible to resolve the external
name at that time, which is what the error message says:

> The error "Cannot reference the signal ... before it has been elaborated."

So a solution is to place the external name references in a process or block
after the DUT is instantiated.

You can also find a related discussion
[here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t700188-external-names-vhdl2008.html).

Comment: To clarify (from the linked discussion), "block" refers specifically to a VHDL `block` statement declarative region. You have to be very careful not to reference the external signal in any way before it is elaborated. For example, `alias`es cannot be used here (but you can declare signals locally in the `block` and assign them with the external signals in the `block` body, which in many cases is acceptable).

Answer (score 2):

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

I have something similar working in vhdl 2008, except  I put the hierarchical signal alias inside of a procedure defined in a package body.  Then when driving one of the alias signals inside of the procedure i used "force in", example:

```
package pkgx is
  procedure write( addr : inout std_logic_Vector(7 downto 0);
end package;

package body pkgx is

  procedure write( addr : inout std_logic_Vector(7 downto 0) is
    alias tap is <<signal .tb.signal3 : std_logic>>;
  begin


    tap <= force in '1';
    wait for 0 ns;
  end procedure;

end package body;
```

Comment: I tried to do this but got Warning: (vsim-1425)  Absolute pathname for a VHDL external name does not start with an entity name that is a design root. Instead, an object with the name <my path in pkg> was found in the scope of design root '(null)'. This object was used as the starting.

Comment: This won't help if you need to connect thoses aliases to any of the testbench instances for monitoring of any other purpose.
What you can do if (see my answer below) have a double declaration. One time in the package (referencing the package in the TB obviously) to make the name visible for compilation and another one inside the procedure to reference them after elaboration. Call the procedure only once at time 0 ns;

Answer (score -1):

This is still the same in 2023 with Questasim latest releases 2023.3_1. Nothing new under the sun.

But I have a working solution. See answer below.

What you need is a double declaration. Keep your initial package declaration as it is with aliases.

Then just add an extra procedure with no parameters in the same package re-declaring the same aliases a second time.

Then call that procedure only once at time 0 ns of your simulation from your testbench.

Surprisingly this double declaration does not offend the compiler.

```
-- assignement after elaboration   
procedure get_external_nets is
     alias signal1 is << signal .tb_top_cfg.TB_TOP_E_INST.DUT.signal1 : std_logic >>;    
begin
     report "reloading external names after whole elaboration";   
end procedure get_external_nets;
```

Comment: I observed the report may sometimes lead to a crash of the tool 
** Fatal: (SIGSEGV) Bad pointer access. Closing vsimk.                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ** Fatal: vsimk is exiting with code 211.
In that case just let package body begin / end empty.